# How to set parameters in request() object

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, request

I am trying to set some parameters to the request scope before calling `server.transfer`, i.e.:

```
request("someParam") = "value"
server.transfer "some.asp"
```

however I get the following error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method: 'request'

How can I set params to the request scope and be able to access them in the `.asp` that I transfer to?

Comment: You can not set (any) parameters using Request(). As the word implies, a Request() will 'request' something, not set/write it.

Comment: @Rich Request implies the scope not the action, as do session() and application().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The Request object retrieves the values that the client browser passed
>   to the server during an HTTP request.

You can't set something to the browser collection that wasn't there in the first place.

If you need it on another page, stuff it in a session variable or append it to a query string in your `Server.Transfer`.